# Validation summary without other validations

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I would like to display the summary of validation in a validation summary with out displaying them in invidual validator means i would like to show only errors in Validation summary i don't want to show in any

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `display="none"` on your validation controls. This will hide the validation text for the individual validation controls.

Then give them all a validation group linked to a `ValidationSummary`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to use both ErrorMessage and Text properties of the Validator controls.

1. Give your Validator controls, post back controls (Buttons, posting Dropdowns etc.) and ValidationSummary control the same ValidationGroup value.
2. Set * on Text property for your Validators.
3. Set the value you want to display on ValidationSummary for each of your Validators to ErrorMessage property.

This way you will have your validation descriptions (ErrorMessage) displayed at ValidationSummary control and a * (Text) displayed next to controls that failed validation.

Comment: It's useful to point out the difference between Text and ErrorMessage but the problem with this solution in this case is that you can't set the Text property to an empty string (or even a space) as it just uses the ErrorMessage property if you do.  You can do as you suggest and set it to  something like * but you can't hide it completely